# edit attribute in xml java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I want to know how to edit an attribute inside of a node which is inside of another node. This would be an example of my xml:

```
<name>Rule_1</name>
<synonymn name="user" class="test.user" />

  <rule name="adult">
    <if leftTerm="user.getAge" op="&gt;" rightTerm="18" />
    <then method="user.mostrarMensaje" arg1="true" />
  </rule>

  <rule name="underAge">
    <if leftTerm="user.getAge" op="&lt;" rightTerm="18" />
    <then method="user.showMessage" arg1="false" />
  </rule>
```

I want to change the attribute rightTerm of each rule to 20 but I can't access it and I'm getting NullReferenceException.

I'm using Java DOM parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Node rule = doc.getElementsByTagName("rule").item(0);

    // update IF attribute
    Node if=rule.getFirstChild();

    NamedNodeMap attr = if.getAttributes();
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("rightTerm");
    nodeAttr.setTextContent("20");
```

or you can do it directly

```
        Node If= doc.getElementsByTagName("if").item(0);
        NamedNodeMap attr = If.getAttributes();
    Node nodeAttr = attr.getNamedItem("rightTerm");
    nodeAttr.setTextContent("20");
```